# Recode name as number in new column but R will not recognize as number

Tags: r

I have data with two columns(column 1 "Gender" is "Male" or "Female")(column 2 is a score on an test.)

I want to recode  the Gender column in a new column (gender 2) that is 0 and 1.  I can do this using.

```
Anxiety$gender2<- NA
```

and then

```
Anxiety$gender2[which(Anxiety$gender=="Male")] <-1
```

and

```
 Anxiety$gender2[which(Anxiety$gender=="Female")] <-2
```

But when I try to correlate using Rcmnd it doesn't recognize the new column as numeric or it does recognize it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `which`. It is unnecessary when subsetting a vector.

```
Anxiety$gender2[Anxiety$gender=="Female"] <-2
```